# Jq: recursively delete all keys that match a given pattern

Tags: json, recursion, key, jq, tree-traversal

How to recursively delete all keys that match a given pattern?

I have following jq config, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
walk( if (type == "object" and (.[] | test('.*'))) then del(.) else . end)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A robust way (with respect to different jq versions) to delete all keys matching a pattern (say PATTERN) would be to use the idiom:

```
with_entries(select( .key | test(PATTERN) | not))
```

Plugging this into `walk/1` yields:

```
walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(select(.key | test(PATTERN) | not)) else . end)
```